# If $\epsilon = \beta_1 \beta_2 ...... \beta_r$ where the $\beta's$ are 2- cycles, then r is even.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If $\epsilon = \beta_1 \beta_2 ...... \beta_r$ where the $\beta's$ are 2- cycles, then r is even.

I just don't understand the proof given in gallian to this, help would be appreciated

Proof: Clearly, r $\neq$1, since a 2 cycle is not the identity. If $r =2$, we are done. So, we suppose that $r>2$ and we proceed by induction.

Since, $(ij) = (ji)$, the product $\beta_{r-1}\beta_r$ can be expressed in one of the following forms shown on the right :

$\epsilon = (ab)(ab)$

$(ab)(bc) = (ac)(ab$

$(ac)(cb) = (bc)(ab)$

$(ab)(cd) = (cd)(ab)$

**What is the use of analyzing such expressions, 2 cycles are still retained?**

If the first case occurs, we may delete $\beta_{r-1}\beta_r$ from the original product to obtain $\epsilon = \beta_1 \beta_2 ...... \beta_{r-2}$.

In the other three cases, we may replace the form of $\beta_{r-1}\beta_r$ on the right by it's counterpart on the left to obtain a new product of $r~ 2$-cycles that is still the identity but where the rightmost occurrence of the integer a is in the second from the rightmost 2 cycle of the product instead of the rightmost 2 cycle. we now repeat the the procedure just described with $\beta_{r-2}\beta_{r-1}$ and as before we obtain a product of $(r-2)$ 2 cycles equal to the identity or a new product of $r ~2$ cycles, where the rightmost occurrence of a is in the third 2 cycle from the right.

Continuing this product we must obtain a product of $(r-2)~ 2$ cycles equal to the identity because otherwise we have a product equal to the identity in which the only occurrence of the integer a is in the leftmost 2 cycle, and such a product does not fix a, whereas the identity does. Hence, by the second principle of mathematical induction, $r-2$ is even and r is even as well.

***So, basically, what they are doing is removing the last terms. The motive's a little confusing, so, can anyone please tell me what they are basically trying to do in a simpler language?***

Thank you

Comment: I don’t get why it’s “or (ab)(ac)”. That seems like something completely else than “(ab)(ab)”.

Comment: I agree that it’s really poorly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have a equation RHS of which is the identity permutation (thus fixing every number) and whose LHS is a permutation which doesn't fix atleast one object ($a$ in the proof) thus arriving at a contradiction.

Observe that if the first case occurs,i.e., $\epsilon=(ab)(ab)$, then you can use induction hypothesis to deduce that $r$ must be even. The remaining portion is arguing that we'll eventually get $r-2$ cycles in rest of the cases also. For that, same representation of the first two-cycles is changed slightly so as to have the occurence of $a$ from the first cycle to the second one. (Note that there is nothing special about $a$ here. You can follow the same procedure with any of the symbols.) Now continue above procedure with the second and third two-cycles. Now $a$ occurs at second position. So we will shift it to $3$rd position. Continuing, we'll get $\epsilon$ = an expression of two-cycles where $a$ occurs exactly in the last cycle. But this is not possible because identity fixes $a$ but in the expression on RHS $a$ is occuring $only\ in$ the last cycle so it can never be fixed as for fixing it we need its occurence in any other cycle of the expression.

Comment: So, a is in the leftmost 2 cycle. Since, the LHS of the equation is identity, there must be one more a in the right 2 cycles.

But, as we saw, the process shown robs the expressions of a and shifts it to the left, Then, how are we ever going to get an identity in the first place?

Comment: that is the desired contradiction...if we reduce the expression to $r-2$ cycles then we are done...if not then we are getting an expression whose LHS is the identity permutation but RHS is not.

Comment: a moves one place to the left at a time, isn't it? Should the number of terms whether even or odd really make a difference then?

because each time a moves to the left, the terms on the right are all disjoint, they must combined be identity. So, what's confusing me is why should the number of terms be even? a keeps on moving one term on the left step by step?

Comment: As per your ques. $a$ moves one place left at a time...in Gallian's book it is one place right...consider a product of two-cycles on $4$ symbols $(23)(34)(24)(12)$...this is not equal to identity and it can never be. why? because $1$ is occuring in the last cycle only so image of $1$ is $2$ so in attempt to make it equal to identity we must have $(21)$ somewhere before in the cycle,i.e., occurence of $1$ before...as far as no.of terms being odd or even...it doesn't make any difference...we are ultimately reducing it to $r-2$ cycles and using induction.

Comment: Sorry but by using the principle of mathematical induction, so we  first assume that r is even?

Comment: why would we assume $r$ to be even ? we need to show that...induction hyothesis is that whenever $\epsilon$ is written as product of 2-cycles whose number is less than $r$ say $k$, then $k$ is even...we are showing that $r-2$ is even...show $r$ must be even...i suggest you work out some examples for that to see that can you ever have identity to be equal to product of odd number of transpositions.

Comment: Thank you. I think i am getting somewhere.

So, the basic idea is that since an identity requires $2$ transpositions ( i.e. an identity in it's basic form is of the form 
$\epsilon = (ab)(ab)$

Hence, we are going on filtering transpositions in sets of 2 ( to the right? ) ; Hence, $r-2$ must be definitely even because only then, we won't be left with a lone term containing a on the left.

So, $r$ must be even.

Does this make sense now?

Comment: yes you're on the right track :)...glad that i could help...notice that it doesn't matter whether you filter toward right or left...in Gallian he is starting moving $a$ from $\beta_1\beta_2$ so to right...you are doing from $\beta_r\beta_{r-1}$ hence to left.

Comment: Thank you . In Gallian 7th edition, he is moving it from βrβr−1 though.

Comment: This is still not very clear.

Comment: Is the idea that any element if moved will have to be moved back again, which will always result in 2n transpositions?