# Identity permutation is product of even number of $2$-cycles proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

The proof on page 103 in Gallian’s 9th edition all makes sense to me except how he concludes that the identity permutation must be equal to $r-2$ $2$-cycles assuming the other three cases. His entire proof is mentioned in [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719491/if-epsilon-beta-1-beta-2-beta-r-where-the-betas-are-2-cycles) Specifically my confusion begins where it says “Continuing…”

I’m also not sure why it’s not just mentioned that the identity could be written in $r-2k$ $2$-cycles where $k$ is how many times the $2$-cycles repeated and cancelled out while filtering the permutation. In other words, why did the filtering process end up canceling exactly two $2$-cycles?

To be clear, I understand why the identity can’t be a product of $r$ $2$-cycles and how it leads to a contradiction. My problem is with how Gallian makes it seem like the identity permutation **has** to be a product of $r-2$ $2$-cycles.

Comment: I think that the point is that as soon as you reduce to $r-2$ transpositions [that is, as soon as you fall into case 1,the $(ab)(ab)$ case] you stop the shuffling process, you don't go on and get other possible cancellations. Then you appeal to the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I see, so all the cases brought up are just meant to create the possibility that $r-2$ $2$-cycles constitute the identity permutation in order to appeal to the induction hypothesis like you said?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I understand how repeating the process again and again, we will eventually exhaust all pair of transpositions. But I don't understand how reducing to $r-2$ cycles gets the job done using induction hypothesis, in that I really just don't understand what is the induction hypothesis here in this case?